# After removing the crlf how to keep the file in its original structure?

Tags: notepad++

After remove the crlf, My notepad file structure changed, all the text becomes in one line. I want to keep it in its original format.

Comment: Well, then at least keep the `lf`. Do you know, what the linefeed (and carriage return) actually does? Also this question is off-topic. Have a try at http://superuser.com

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I have some script file for python and also text file . all on a sudden in every file after the line 'crlf' appread.  i can remove them following -search - replace - /n  /r . after remove my script file doesn't stay in original format. all the text wrap up in one line ! i want to keep the file in its original format!

Comment: Check the sub-options of **Menu** -> **View** -> **Show symbol** perhaps **Show end of line** or **Show all symbols** are selected.

Comment: @ adrian HHH you are the best

Answer (score 0):

Notepad++ has options for showing symbols not normally shown, they are controlled by the sub options of menu -> **View** -> **Show symbol**.

When **Show end of line** is selected then the actual CRs and LFs in the file will be shown with white letters on a black background. With this option the CRs and LFs are shown after any trailing white space on the line.

When **Show white space** is selected then spaces and tab characters will be shown with a small centred dot and an arrow, respectively, both in orange. This options allows trailing white space on lines to be clearly seen.

The option **Show all characters** combines the other two.